# ASP.NET Core Html Helper rendering raw text instead of formatted HTML using TagBuilder

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm working on an Html Helper to create a control that will consist of multiple elements, build using `TagBuilder`s. The control itself will be rendered using a `TagBuilder` that contains a `div` with all child elements.

Per this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/17287/tagbuilder-tostring-returns-the-type-of-tagbuilder.html

I implemented a `Render()` method to create the control and return it as a `string`:

```
public class MyCustomControl
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Render();
    }

    private string Render()
    {
        TagBuilder mainContainer = new TagBuilder("div");

        // Generate child elements and append to mainContainer...

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            mainContainer.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);

            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And made an extension method to call it in a Razor View:

```
public static MyCustomControl(this IHtmlHelper html)
{
    return new MyCustomControl();
}
```

And include it in Views like this:

```
@(Html.MyCustomControl()
)
```

The problem is instead of being rendered html, I get raw html text output to the View, so I actually see:

```
<div><!-- all child controls html here --></div>
```

Instead of there being an element there.

Comment: You’re describing the opposite; you’re outputting HTML encoded text so that you see what looks like HTML on your page.  You *want* to output raw HTML in this case so remove the encoding.

Comment: `TagBuilder.WriteTo` requires an `HtmlEncoder` and `Default` is the only implementation available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return an instance of `IHtmlContent` instead of `string` :

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtension {
    public static IHtmlContent MyCustomControl(this IHtmlHelper html)
    {
        var result = new MyCustomControl();
        return html.Raw(result.Render());
    }
}
```

Test Case :

```
public class MyCustomControl
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Render();
    }

    public string Render()
    {
        TagBuilder mainContainer = new TagBuilder("div");
        mainContainer.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data-id","123") );

        // Generate child elements and append to mainContainer...

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            mainContainer.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);

            var result=writer.ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

the result will be :

```
<div data-id="123"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better way to do this is to implement IHtmlContent in your custom control, like so:

```
public class MyCustomControl : IHtmlContent
{
    public void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
    {
        TagBuilder mainContainer = new TagBuilder("div");

        // Generate child elements and append to mainContainer...

        mainContainer.WriteTo(writer, encoder);
    }
}
```

then your HtmlHelper extension doesn't change all that much:

```
public static IHtmlContent MyCustomControl(this IHtmlHelper html)
{
    return new MyCustomControl();
}
```

This should eliminate the temporary strings which are created in the accepted answer.